# Registration Form Validation for the

Tags: forms, validation, registration

I am a Software Quality Assurance and i want to check a registration form validation and also i want to check that fields validation

Please help and suggest that how we can check?

Thanku

Comment: So.. On which platform/language do you want this? You need to be more specific for people to help you out here.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it by the following ways

- By by pressing save button with empty fields whether it insert empty data or not if do so then validate it not to insert empty data.
- By checking which fields are mandatory.
- By checking whether the user is already register or not.
- By entering digits in alphabates fields like name or fathername which must be alphabets only.
- By entering Alphabets in digits fields like phone no or Fax no which must be alphabets only.
- If there is password fields by comparing both fields whether they are same or not.

There are many others i have write some of them. May this helps you. Please don't forget to mark as answer if it helps. Thanks